# How to query all documents exclude the latest docucment base on time

Tags: mongoose, document

How to query all documents of user "52ecdb4ea6b03a94179612de" exclude the latest docucment  (document with "article":"aa", "created": ISODate("2014-02-01T13:03:47.577Z") in this case)?

```
{
  "article":"aa",
  "user": ObjectId("52ecdb4ea6b03a94179612de"),
  "comment": "222222222",
  "created": ISODate("2014-02-01T13:03:47.577Z"),

},
{
  "article": "bb",
  "user": ObjectId("52ecdb4ea6b03a94179612de"),
  "comment": "222222222",
  "created": ISODate("2014-01-01T13:03:47.577Z"),

},
{
  "article": "cc",
  "user": ObjectId("52ecdb4ea6b03a94179612de"),
  "comment": "222222222",
  "created": ISODate("2013-01-01T13:03:47.577Z"),

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter by `user`, sort by `created` descending, and then skip the first doc:

```js
MyModel.find({user: '52ecdb4ea6b03a94179612de'}).sort('-created').skip(1)
    .exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
```